# Ctrl+click doesn't work after converting to AspectJ Project

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, aspectj, ajdt

After I enabled AspectJ nature in my SpringBoot project the `CTRL + click` shortcut doesn't work. When I try to use `F3` I get error:
[image: Error after using F3]
`CTRL + click` or `F3` works only on class field names (can't click class field type) or constructors. Problem is solved when I click on `project -> AspectJ Tools -> Remove AspectJ Capability`. This is my STS and AJDT version:

```
Spring Tool Suite 

Version: 3.7.3.RELEASE
Build Id: 201602251025
Platform: Eclipse Neon (4.6)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was a problem when the AJDT version inside STS was still purely mars based. There is a new AJDT version more compatible with neon available from this update site:
    http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/46/dev/update

If you update from there, the problem should be addressed. And that will be folded into the next STS.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your response. It's correct to assume that, in general, error with `NameEnvironmentAnswer` are related to wrong version of plugin (not compatible with eclipse version)?

Comment: It just happened to be `NameEnvironmentAnswer` in this case, but it could be anything in the eclipse platform changing that leaves us incompatible. Ideally we should have caught this even sooner and fixed it before release but didn't - we'll try harder next time!